# Mapping JSON response to different types

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, mapping

I'm using Spring 2.6 and we make a GET request via

`restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, ResponseType.class).getBody();`

The JSON response can be of two kinds:

1st:

```
public class ResponseType {

    private String data;

}
```

2nd:

```
public class ResponseType {

    private Subclass data;

}

public class Subclass {

    private String classId;
    private String detail;

}
```

In the first version I only get a reference link to the subclass resource.
If the URL contains a 'resolve' flag, than the reference link get expanded already in the first request.
The classId then also specifies what kind of class it is ( 'a.b.c' or 'x.y.z' )

No problem for JSON, but how can I get a mapping in Java?

When having more fields being dynamic (link or instance based on classId) a manual way would be difficult to implement if the combination could be 2 links and 3 objects.
It also could be that a object has the same feature - a filed with a link or a instance of a class specified by classId.

The JSON response would be this:

```
{  
 "data": "abskasdkjhkjsahfkajdf-linkToResource" 
}
```

or this:

```
 {  
  "data": {
   "classId": "a.b.subclass",    
   "detail": "some data"   
  } 
}
```

or this:

```
 {  
  "data": {
   "classId": "a.b.subclass",    
   "detail": "some data"
   "data2": "some-link-id",
   "data3": {
     "detailB": "foo",
     "detailC": "some-link-id"
   } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Are the classIds both "a.b.subclass" or can we know something about the structure from the classId? Are all the different JSON structures known before they are received?

Comment: The source to map is a big set of entites structured in a tree with subclasses.

All the classes are known. I'm mapping the big tree to a smaller one with less attributes (need to know principle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I do have a possible solution for my problem. The logic to print the address only or the POJO relies soley in the CustomItemSerializer. So it is possible to use this without using duplicate code in controllers.

```
package com.allianz.clana.datamodel.http.epc.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

public class JacksonTester2 {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException, JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        Item item2 = new Item("link");
        
        Stuff stuff = new Stuff();
        
        stuff.setItem(item2);
        stuff.setFoo("foo");
        
        String jsonStringStuff = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(stuff);
        System.out.println(jsonStringStuff);

        Item item3 = new Item("{ \"name\":\"ID3\", \"creationDate\":\"1984-12-30\", \"rollNo\": 1 }");
        
        stuff.setItem(item3);
        stuff.setFoo("bar");
        
        jsonStringStuff = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(stuff);
        System.out.println(jsonStringStuff);
        
    }
}

class CustomItemSerializer extends StdSerializer<Item> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    public CustomItemSerializer() {
        this(null);
    }
    
    public CustomItemSerializer(Class<Item> t) {
        super(t);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void serialize(Item item, JsonGenerator generator, SerializerProvider arg2) throws IOException {
        if (item != null) {
            if (item.getItem() != null) {
                System.out.println("ItemA POJO data");
                generator.writePOJO(item.getItem());
            } else {
                System.out.println("raw data with link");
                generator.writeString(item.getRawdata());
            }
        } 
    }
}

@Data
class Stuff {
    Item item;
    String foo;
}

@JsonSerialize(using = CustomItemSerializer.class)
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
class Item {
    private String rawdata;
    @JsonIgnore
    private ItemA item;
    
    public Item(String rawdata) {
        this.rawdata = rawdata;
        if (rawdata.contains("{")) {
            try {
                this.item = new ObjectMapper().readerFor(ItemA.class).readValue(rawdata);
            } catch (JsonMappingException  e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } 
    }
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
class ItemA{
    private String name;
    private int rollNo;
    private String creationDate;

    public ItemA(String name, int rollNo, String dob) {
        this.name = name;
        this.rollNo = rollNo;
        this.creationDate = dob;
    }
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
raw data with link
{
  "item" : "link",
  "foo" : "foo"
}

ItemA POJO data
{
  "item" : {
    "name" : "ID3",
    "rollNo" : 1,
    "creationDate" : "1984-12-30"
  },
  "foo" : "bar"
}
```

The CustomItemSerializer decides if the link is printed or the POJO.